# how to detect centroid & measure distance between two objects ?? using birdeyeview?

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, computer-vision, artificial-intelligence

i want to detect moving  person & its centroid (without using centroidtracker) ,i have video of walking  people,

this is my code

```
import cv2

face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
frame=cv2.imread('person.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)

for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
    cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 3)

    cX = int((x+ w) / 2.0)
    cY = int((y + h) / 2.0)

   print(cX)
   print(cY)
   cv2.circle(frame, (cX, cY), 10, (205, 0, 255), -1)
   cv2.imshow('img',frame)
   if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
    break
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image: im getting this output ,please tell me whats wrong in my code]

Comment: This is not a bird's eye view.  Why are your bounding boxes not tighter to the figure?  For this, if you want to measure distance, I would assume the bottom of the bounding box was at ground level. Otherwise with the centroid, you will have to assume the people are the same heights and know the vertical height in world coord to measure 3D distance. Using the bottom means the vertical dimension is zero.

Comment: yes its not ,but im planing to solve this problem using birdeyeviw

Answer (score 0):

This is code in which you can detect person & find its centroid + distance.

```
import cv2
import math


face_cascade=cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
frame=cv2.imread('dis456.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.1, 4)
print(faces)


p1 = 361  # image pont
p2 = 237
cv2.circle(frame, (p1, p2), 5, ((139,0,0)), -1)
for face in faces:
   (x, y, w, h) = face
   (x1, y1, w1, h1) = faces[0]


   cx1, cy1 = int(x + w / 2), int(y + h / 2)
   cx2, cy2 = int(x1 + w1 / 2), int(y1 + h1 / 2)

   cv2.circle(frame, (cx1, cy1), 2, (0, 245, 30), -1)
   cv2.circle(frame, (cx2, cy2), 2, (0, 245, 30), -1)

  # dist=math.sqrt(((cx1-cx2)**2)+(cy2-cy1)**2))
   cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 3)

   dis = (math.sqrt(((cx2 - cx1) ** 2) + ((cy2 - cy1) ** 2)) ** 0.5)
   dis = int(dis)
   print("distance is ",dis)
   cv2.line(frame, (cx1, cy1), (p1,p2 ), (0, 234, 76), 2)

  (x,y,w,h)=face
  cv2.putText(frame, 'distance={}'.format(dis), (x, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX, 0.6, 
 (139, 0, 0))




cv2.imshow('img',frame)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: im uploading all code in my github account for birdseye view prespective transformation.